# K esimo elemento en un ABB arbol binario de busqueda

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer una funcion que encuentre el elemento con posicion k dentro de un arbol binario de busqueda (ABB).
Tengo que recorrerlo en orden, o sea, izquierda, raiz, derecha.
Hasta ahora tengo este codigo pero me da Segmentation fault. 
Si tienen otra forma de implementarlo tambien me sirve.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué implementación de [árbol binario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) usas? rooted binary, full binary, perfect binary, complete binary, infinite complete binary, balanced binary... ¿o alguna implementación no mencionada en la [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)? ¿cuál es la definición del tipo `binario`? ¿cuál es la definición del tipo `nat`?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para añadir la información que falta. Los comentarios no tienen garantía de persistencia (es decir, pueden ser borrados en el futuro) así que para que tu pregunta sea completa, necesitará los datos que has añadido como comentarios.

Comment: debajo de la etiqueta de la pregunta tienes una serie de opciones a realizar sobre la pregunta... busca "_editar_". El enlace en cuestión es https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65018/edit

Comment: ¿y qué es `info_t`?

Comment: ¿y qué es `texto_t`?

Comment: En tu última edición... fíjate que siempre haces `nat contador=0`, con eso solo conseguirás que te devuelva el primer elemento **siempre**

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar la variable `k` como índice en vez de `contador`?

Comment: `binario nodo = buscar_kesimo(b,&k);`

Comment: Un consejo: Ponte las pilas con los conceptos básicos del lenguaje... en el examen no vamos a poder estar ahí para echarte una mano

Answer (score 1):

```
static info_t aux_kesimo(nat k, binario b, nat contador){
```

Si tu intención es realizar una llamada recursiva lamento comunicarte que con esta función no va a ser posible. El motivo es que antes de procesar el nodo en cuestión tienes que procesar antes su rama izquierda y eso puede desencadenar un número indeterminado de llamadas que no tienes forma de contabilizar, luego no vas a saber cuándo llegas al elemento `contador`.

Además la función es totalmente inutil:

```
static info_t aux_kesimo(nat k, binario b, nat contador){

    return aux_kesimo(k, b->izq, contador); // <<--- (1)

    if(++contador == k){
        return b->dato; // <<--- (2)
    }

    return aux_kesimo(k, b->der, contador); // <<--- (3)
}
```

Según el código **siempre**  se ejecutará el `return` (1), lo que impedirá que los `return` (2) y (3) se puedan ejecutar en algún momento.

Necesitarías una función auxiliar como por ejemplo:

```
binario* buscar_kesimo(binario nodo, nat* contador)
{
  binario* toReturn = 0;

  if( nodo->izq )
    toReturn = buscar_kesimo(nodo->izq,contador);

  if( !toReturn )
  {
    if( *contador == 0 )
      toReturn = nodo;
    else
      *contador--; // el contador solo se actualiza al procesar el nodo
  }

  if( !toReturn && nodo->der )
    toReturn = buscar_kesimo(nodo->der,contador);

  return toReturn;
}
```

Con lo cual tu función podría quedar así:

```
static info_t aux_kesimo(nat k, binario b, nat contador){
  binario nodo = buscar_kesimo(b,&contador);

  if( nodo )
    return nodo->dato;
  else
    // No hay nodo con el indice dado
}
```

Comment: @sabri128 si no das más información...